# Spring Security 5 - Bad Credentials at Login despite correct email and password

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, bcrypt

I have been trying to solve this since a week and tried all posts and still could not get this work. 
My SecurityConfiguration Class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;


    public SecurityConfiguration(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder, DataSource dataSource) {
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                ;


    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {



        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/h2-console/**","/registration","/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/offer/**").access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }
}
```

and I have a WebMvcConfiguration Class as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
}
```

I just keep getting "Bad credentials" and that the password does not match the records. I can see the hashed password in the database and setting up a debug point just before the line where the DaoAuthenticationProvider Class throws this exception (additionalAuthenticationChecks method) and as far as I can see, the user details from the database are coming correctly but it does not show the presented password at login as encoded...

My Login Controller is as follows:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private final UserAccountService userAccountService;


    public LoginController(UserAccountService userAccountService) {
        this.userAccountService = userAccountService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login( Error error){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("error page");
        }
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid UserAccount user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        UserAccount userExists = userAccountService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (userExists != null) {
            bindingResult
                    .rejectValue("email", "error.user",
                            "There is already a user registered with the email provided");
        }
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("registration");
        } else {
            userAccountService.saveOrUpdate(user);
            modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "User has been registered successfully");
            modelAndView.addObject("user", new UserAccount());
            modelAndView.setViewName("registration");

        }
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin/home")
    public ModelAndView home(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        UserAccount user = userAccountService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
        modelAndView.addObject("userName", "Welcome " + user.getFirstName() + " "
                + user.getLastName() + " (" + user.getEmail() + ")");
        modelAndView.addObject("adminMessage","Content Available Only for Users with Admin Role");
        modelAndView.setViewName("admin/home");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

My SQL queries also are working correctly , I have tried them out on H2 console...

what do you think,I am doing wrong?

Comment: $2a$10$HwZisjNuFqVpiNeq399cKOUPZH8LVsKbQS4sniZeyewixc4a3eRP2 is the hashed and 1234 is what I enter when logging in..

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the culprit:

When starting up the app, I was populating database with some test data and I have realized that I was updating the user accounts, where the passwords were getting re-encoded...

Once I have reduced the use of "saveOrUpdate" method of UserAccount class, I was able to login.